# Añadir un objeto a un array de objetos en javascript sin uso de push, unshift, etc

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Trato de añadir un objeto al array de objetos en javascript sin usar los métodos push, shift, etc, sino directamente al arreglo, pero me muestra error que no esta la propiedad definida, esto se puede hacer ?

```
let contacts = [{
    name: "Maxwell Wright",
    phone: "(0191) 719 6495",
    email: "Curabitur.egestas.nunc@nonummyac.co.uk"
}, {
    name: "Raja Villarreal",
    phone: "0866 398 2895",
    email: "posuere.vulputate@sed.com"
}, {
    name: "Helen Richards",
    phone: "0800 1111",
    email: "libero@convallis.edu"
}];



function addNewContact(contactList,name,phone,email){
        contactList[contactList.length] = {};
        contactList[contactList.length].name = name;
        contactList[contactList.length].phone = phone;
        contactList[contactList.length].email = email;
    return 1;
}
addNewContact(contacts,"Ana","67777777","ww@a.com");
```

Mensaje de error mostrado:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'name')

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo tan sencillo como:

```js
let contacts = [
  {
    name: "Maxwell Wright",
    phone: "(0191) 719 6495",
    email: "Curabitur.egestas.nunc@nonummyac.co.uk",
  },
  {
    name: "Raja Villarreal",
    phone: "0866 398 2895",
    email: "posuere.vulputate@sed.com",
  },
  {
    name: "Helen Richards",
    phone: "0800 1111",
    email: "libero@convallis.edu",
  },
];

const addNewContact = (contactList, name, phone, email) => (contactList[contactList.length] = { name, phone, email })

addNewContact(
  contacts,
  "An123asdasda",
  "6777sdsdasdasd7777",
  "ww@a.comaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
);

console.log(contacts);
```

Estoy usando una función flecha (que puede resumir bastante una función en ciertas ocasiones), y asigno a la nueva posición del arreglo un 'literal de objeto', no necesito colocar todas las propiedades de la forma *propiedad: valor*, basta con poner solo el nombre del parámetro y el nombre de ese parámetro sera el nombre de la propiedad y el valor de dicha propiedad sera, el valor del parámetro.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta me ayuda mucho a ir entiendo mejor

Answer (score 1):

Te devuelve `undefined` porque estás tratando de acceder a un índice que aún no existe en el array.

---

Véase que con esto añades un objeto vacío al final del array de objetos `contacts`:

```
contactList[contactList.length] = {};
```

Entonces, tendrías que posicionarte a ese último índice del array, quien sería el nuevo objeto vacío creado:

```
let lastIndex = contactList.length - 1;
```

Y en ese último índice, agregas los elementos correspondientes:

```
contactList[lastIndex].name = name;
contactList[lastIndex].phone = phone;
contactList[lastIndex].email = email;
```

### Ejemplo:

```js
let contacts = [
  {
    name: 'Maxwell Wright',
    phone: '(0191) 719 6495',
    email: 'Curabitur.egestas.nunc@nonummyac.co.uk',
  },
  {
    name: 'Raja Villarreal',
    phone: '0866 398 2895',
    email: 'posuere.vulputate@sed.com',
  },
  {
    name: 'Helen Richards',
    phone: '0800 1111',
    email: 'libero@convallis.edu',
  },
];

function addNewContact(contactList, name, phone, email) {
  contactList[contactList.length] = {}; // Agregamos un objeto vacío al final del array.
  let lastIndex = contactList.length - 1; // Obtenemos el último índice del array, quien sería el último objeto agregado.

  // y en ese objeto, agregamos las claves y valores correspondientes.
  contactList[lastIndex].name = name;
  contactList[lastIndex].phone = phone;
  contactList[lastIndex].email = email;

  return 1;
}

console.log(contacts);
addNewContact(contacts, 'Ana', '67777777', 'ww@a.com');
console.log(contacts);
```

Answer (score 1):

El error en su función `addNewContact(`) ocurre al intentar asignar la propiedad name a un objeto que no existe, la propiedad name no existe en el objeto *contactList* **[**contactList.length**]**.

**-** *Una solución es aumentar el tamaño del array y agregar nuevos valores en la última posición.*

```js
let contacts = [];

function addNewContact(contactList, name, phone, email) {      
    contactList.length = contactList.length + 1;  // Amplíe el tamaño del array.
    contactList[contactList.length - 1] = { // Agrega el nuevo contacto a la última posición.
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        email: email
    }

}

addNewContact(contacts, "Ana 1","67777777","ww@a.com"); 
addNewContact(contacts, "Ana 2","67777777","ww@a.com"); 

console.log(contacts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que nadie te ha explicado bien tu problema, el cual es:

```js
function addNewContact(contactList,name,phone,email){

        //Aquí contactList.length es 3  

        contactList[contactList.length] = {};

        //Ahora contactList.length es 4, porque le agregaste el indice=3


        //De aquí en más estas trabajando con el índice 4 en lugar del 3,
        //y es el problema en cuestion
        contactList[contactList.length].name = name;
        contactList[contactList.length].phone = phone;
        contactList[contactList.length].email = email;
```

Entonces, basta con que guardes el índice:

```js
function addNewContact(contactList,name,phone,email){
        const indice = contactList.length;
        contactList[indice] = {};
        contactList[indice].name = name;
        contactList[indice].phone = phone;
        contactList[indice].email = email;
    return 1;
}
```

---

Ahora bien, si estas agregando siempre al final, no hay motivo para no usar `push`

```
const addNewContact = (contactList, name, phone, email) 
=> contactList.push({ name, phone, email });
```